# generic make rule assitance when placing files into different folders

Tags: makefile

I have a make rule like this. I want it to define a generic rule that describes transformation of any C file into compiled Object file. It works fine, but i want to keep my C files in one folder and output files in another.

Here is the relevant snippet from Makefile itself:

```
 .SUFFIXES .c .o


.c.o :
    $(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I want to modify this makefile rule to tell make to find the source (C) files in one folder, let's say `$(C_DIR)`, run GCC and then and put OBJ files into `$(O_DIR)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with suffix rules.  In order to do that you'll have to use non-POSIX-standard make features.  GNU make (the standard make on GNU/Linux systems for example, and available for pretty much any other platform) provides pattern rules that can do this:

```
SRCS = foo.c bar.c baz.c

OBJS = $(addprefix $(O_DIR)/,$(SRCS))

all: $(OBJS)

$(O_DIR)/%.o : $(C_DIR)/%.c
        $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Note you don't need the `.SUFFIXES:` target at all for pattern rules.